# Convert string xpath into XML

Tags: xml, scala, typesafe

I have the following string i loaded by typesafe ConfigFactory.

Conf.conf:

```
xpath {
    test = """"region"/"city"/"street"/"apartment""""
}
```

Then i convert it to suitable format (back slash to forward slash "region"\"city"\"street"\"apartment"):

```
val conf = ConfigFactory.load("Conf.conf").getString("xpath.test")
val test = conf.replace("/","\\")
```

I have XML file:

```
val xml_file = XML.load("PATHtoXML")
```

so that to further find value of "test" in "xml_file". In general it works like : (xml_file \ "xx" \ "yyy" \ "dddd").text. 
However I'm stuck to getting value in my case:

```
val res = (xml_file \\ test).text
println(s"Result -> ${res}")
```

it returns nothing.

Would you please give me some hints to solve it.

many thanks!

Comment: Debugging revealed that actually "region\city\street\apartment" is used.

Comment: Could you provide an extract of your XML file?

Comment: This is a piece of XML: <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?><fpml: fpml xmlns......version="2-0-2"><fpml: region><fpml:city><fpml:street id="street1"><fpml:apartment>13495</fpml:apartment></fpml:street></fpml:city></fpml:region>

Answer (score 0):

If it is not against your requirements, you can use [standard Java library to parse your XML file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2811001/how-to-read-xml-using-xpath-in-java). To my opinion, it is more flexible than Scala XML, because as far as I know, with the latter, you could not use easily an XPath expression as a `String`. You can just iterate with `\\` and `\` operators, like :

```scala
val res: String = (xml \\ "region" \ "city" \ "street" \ "apartment").text
```

With Java library, you can do the following (example based on the accepted answer of the SO post I provided above) :

```scala
import javax.xml.parsers.DocumentBuilderFactory
import javax.xml.xpath.XPathFactory

val factory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance
val builder = factory.newDocumentBuilder
val doc = builder.parse("PATHtoXML")

val xPathfactory = XPathFactory.newInstance
val xpath = xPathfactory.newXPath
val conf = "region/city/street/apartment"
val expr = xpath.compile(conf)

val res = expr.evaluate(doc)
println(s"Result -> ${res}")
```

You can also define your `Conf.conf` like :

```
xpath {
    test = "region/city/street/apartment"
}
```

And use it by replacing `conf` above with :

```
val conf = ConfigFactory.load("Conf.conf").getString("xpath.test")
```

Comment: thank you very much for your solution. I will try it